# How to remove border around nivo slider

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

i have a problem that I cant remove black border around nivo slider, i used png images to make my slideshow shape better. thanks

Comment: in all browser?? or only specific browser it appears

Comment: i tested in chrome and firefox, both have the same issue

Comment: Can we see some code, a live example. Or both?

Comment: nothing special, simple code downloaded from nivo-slider website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, there was a box-shadow in default.css file which comes with the plugin, just needed to delete that.